# Memory Address Block diagram

Tags: memory-hardware

Given A memory chip that has 4-addresses and each address location holds 8-bits is denoted as (4×8) RAM chip.

I want to draw a block-diagram showing the memory address that the first 3 chips will hold if using low and high order interleaving.

Does anyone have any similar examples? I am completely lost.

Comment: What have you been introduced to regarding address/memory interleaving?